# Connecting Silverlight client to SignalR server

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, client-server, signalr

I've been driving myself nuts trying to resolve this issue so really hoping someone has some insight.

I have a console application which runs/hosts my signalR server.
I have already successfully connected to it using a web(javascript) client and a windows forms client with no trouble at all.

BUT for the life of me I cannot get a silverlight client to connect to it.  Initially I was getting a

'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in Microsoft.Threading.Tasks error

on

await Connection.Start();

I managed to fix that by force sending the clientaccesspolicy file using code i found on a random thread.

[THREAD](http://forums.asp.net/t/1943506.aspx?SignalR+2+0+rc1+self+host+server+Silverlight+client)

However the connection still never establishes.  The status goes thru connecting, disconnected, connection closed.

I am at my wits end as to why this won't work.  Any input is appreciated. Code below.

```
MainPage.xaml.cs
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    private SignalRClient client;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = new ItemsCollection();

        client = new SignalRClient();
        client.RunAsync();

        Debug.WriteLine("Init Done");
    }
}
```

-

```
SignalRClient.cs
public class SignalRClient
{
    private HubConnection Connection { get; set; }
    private IHubProxy HubProxy { get; set; }

    const string url = "http://localhost:8080/";

    public SignalRClient()
    {

    }

    public async void RunAsync()
    {
        Connection = new HubConnection(url, useDefaultUrl: true);
        Connection.Closed += Connection_Closed;
        Connection.StateChanged += ConnectionDidSomething;

        HubProxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("TickerHub");
        HubProxy.On<string>("receiveAllData", data => Debug.WriteLine("RECDATA={0}", data));

        try
        {
            await Connection.Start();
        }
        catch (HttpClientException e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Unable to connect to server.1 {0}", e.Message);
            return;
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Unable to connect to server.2 {0}", e.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
```

-

```
Server
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        string url = "http://localhost:8080/";
        using (WebApp.Start(url))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SignalR server running on {0}", url);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }            

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Configuration");

        //Tried this approach too
        /*app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {                
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                EnableJSONP = true
            };
            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });*/

        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR<ClientAccessPolicyConnection>("/clientaccesspolicy.xml");
    }
}
```

-

```
TickerHub.cs
public class TickerHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        string connectionID = Context.ConnectionId;
        Console.WriteLine("New Connection:" + connectionID);

        InitNewClient(connectionID);

        return base.OnConnected();            
    }

    //send all data to newly connected client
    public void InitNewClient(string connectionID)
    {
    }

    //client requested all data
    public void GetAllData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Get Data Triggered");         

        Clients.All.receiveAllData("TESTING123");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out!  Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Its quite simple.  This is what you need to have in your startup class configuration method. 
Below that is the code required to send the clientaccesspolicy.xml.

```
class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Branch the pipeline here for requests that start with "/signalr"
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            // Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR.
            // By default this will allow all origins. You can 
            // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
            // providing a cors options with a different policy.
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
                // JSONP requests are insecure but some older browsers (and some
                // versions of IE) require JSONP to work cross domain
                EnableJSONP = true
            };
            // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
            // since this branch already runs under the "/signalr"
            // path.
            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });

        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR<ClientAccessPolicyConnection>("/clientaccesspolicy.xml");
    }
}
```

-

```
public class ClientAccessPolicyConnection : PersistentConnection
{
    public override Task ProcessRequest(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.HostContext context)
    {
        string[] urlArray = context.Request.Url.ToString().Split('/');

        string path = urlArray[urlArray.Length - 1];

        if (path.Equals("clientaccesspolicy.xml", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            //Convert policy to byteArray
            var array = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ClientAccessPolicy);
            var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(array);

            //Write response
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
            context.Response.Write(segment);

            //Return empty task to escape from SignalR's default Connection/Transport checks.
            return EmptyTask;
        }

        return EmptyTask;
    }

    private static readonly Task EmptyTask = MakeTask<object>(null);

    public static Task<T> MakeTask<T>(T value)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        tcs.SetResult(value);
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public static readonly string ClientAccessPolicy =
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                + "<access-policy>"
                   + "<cross-domain-access>"
                     + "<policy>"
                       + "<allow-from http-request-headers=\"*\">"
                            + "<domain uri=\"*\"/>"
                       + "</allow-from>"
                       + "<grant-to>"
                            + "<resource path=\"/\" include-subpaths=\"true\"/>"
                       + "</grant-to>"
                    + "</policy>"
                + "</cross-domain-access>"
              + "</access-policy>";
}
```